# Dygraph: how to clear the graph data and reload it?

Tags: graph, dygraphs

My application has refresh functionality in which all the present data on the graph should get cleared and data should be loaded from starting. I don't want to destroy the dygraph and recreate it but just need to clear the existing data and plot from starting.
What I tried is

g.rawdata_ =  null;
g.updateOptions({'file': g.rawdata_});

But it throws the error. If i set rawdata to 0 and then try to update, it doesn't clear off the data. 
Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: If you just want the dygraph to redraw, then g.updateOptions({}) will work. If you want to load new data, you should call g.updateOptions({file: newData}). Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Suppose I have plotted few data series on the track, now my app has a refresh button. On the click of this button, the already plotted data should be omitted from the track and plotting should restart on basis of new data. Using the g.updateOptions({}) doesn't clears off the existing data. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: dygraphs just charts whatever data you give it. You'll need to make sure the data is correct yourself!

Comment: Did you found solution? I have same issue!

Comment: As of official annotation http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html, for simple graph refresh: 'Calling dygraph.setAnnotations(dygraph.annotations()) is a no-op: it simply causes the chart to refresh.'

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just like the guys in the comments are saying:

```
plotData = [[0,0]];

g.updateOptions(
    { 
        'file': plotData
    }
);
```

plotData has to have *something* in it.  You could probably put one of several different formats, but the above has worked for me in the past.  I am live updating a plot as well and refreshing the data every second.  To do that, I am preloading the plotData just before the updateOptions.

Good luck,

j

Answer (score 3):

I was facing almost the same issue. I have charts that refresh when user clicks the button. The handle to the dygraphs is a local variable, for ex.,

```
var g = new Dygraph(...
```

This is called inside a function. The problem was the graph and all variables it was referencing (element, data, etc.) are never being destroyed and stays in the memory.

My workaround was to have a global object, with chart_id as key and the handle to the chart as the value and every time the same chart_id is called I check if handle already exists in global object and destroy if it did. This is how it looked,

```
if(chart_handle[chart_id])
{
   chart_handle[chart_id].destroy();
}
chart_handle[chart_id] = new Dygraph(...
```

Comment: Is `chart_handle[chart_id].destroy(); delete chart_handle[chart_id];` the correct way to remove the Dygraph object from the memory? The main issue is that I couldn't find anything related to this question(how to remove the graph) in their docs.